# how to check data exist in database before inserting in php

Tags: php

```
$sqlorg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `organization`");
while($orgrows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlorg)) {
    //$dborgid = $orgrows['org_id'];
    $dborgnme = $orgrows['org_name'];
}

if ($dborgnme == $orgexist) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Organization Name Already Used by other Organization');
            history.back();
        </script>";
} else {
    $orginsrt = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `organization`(`org_id`,`org_name`,`org_desc`,`category`,`vision`,`mission`,`col_id`,`image`) VALUES ('$orgid','$orgexist','$orgdesc','$orgcat','$orgvis','$orgmis','$getcol','$image')");

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Proceed to next Step');</script>";
        //require ('orgsignup.php');
        header ('Location:orgsignup2.php');
    //echo "Not in the Record";

}
```

Comment: i cannot find the correct comparing in my declaration..

Comment: There are better ways of resolving this. What's your plan and what's your table's structure? Unique cols...

Comment: **Don't**! Enforce uniqueness for the column(s) in the database.

Comment: mysql functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO. This code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: $orgexist = $_POST['orgName1']; -- that the name of the textbox from my form

Comment: i don't even know how to use the mysqli

Comment: i don't know how to insert data when there is already existing data from database...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with this question, and as such can't easily be answered - I'm writing this "answer" as a quick guide to Kio Rii and to get more information:

1) **Don't** use MySQL, use MySQLi for procedural DB/PHP interactions.

2)

```
while($orgrows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlorg)) {
    //$dborgid = $orgrows['org_id'];
    $dborgnme = $orgrows['org_name'];
}
```

The value `$dborgnme` will only ever hold the final value from all the rows fetched from the database. Consider reformatting the `While` statement to wrap outside the following `if(){} ... else{}`

3) Add some context and information to your question - what are you checking for? Where do values such as `$orgexist` come from? What events do you want to occur if a data exists or what happens if a data doesn't exist?

4) If you're only checking the name, you can better do it with a better SELECT statement as the current select is grabbing all the MySQL rows, so try

take :

```
$sqlorg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `organization`");
```

and turn it into

```
$sqlorg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `organization` WHERE org_name LIKE '%".$orgexist."%' ");
```

which will only return you rows if the names are very similar. You can then use the output of this (count of rows returned) to carry on the script logic.

5) Yes, my solution in part 4 is quick and dirty, and PDO or MySQLi prepared statements are much, MUCH better and more secure than old MySQL and variable injection into the SQL statement.

### Additional debugging:

you would probably find this very useful:

```
$orginsrt = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `organization`(`org_id`,`org_name`,`org_desc`,`category`,`vision`,`mission`,`col_id`,`image`) VALUES ('$orgid','$orgexist','$orgdesc','$orgcat','$orgvis','$orgmis','$getcol','$image')") or die("insert fail: ".mysql_error());
```

This will tell you why an insert failed, if it did fail.

Comment: $orgexist = $_POST['orgName1']; -- that the name of the textbox from my form

Comment: i don't even know how to use the mysqli

Comment: i don't know how to insert data when there is already existing data from database...

Comment: add your first comment to the main question, please. for MySQLi read up on it on Google or on Stack Overflow, it's not difficult to use it once you read about the changes. Thirdly, your MySQL `INSERT` statement doesn't need to insert "autoincrement" values, such as org_id. Don't do it, these values are automatically generated by the database and help hugely with organisation.

Comment: i'll already remove that one... my main problem is why i cannot insert in database when there no match from the database

Comment: @KioRii read the section underneath the big letters that say "additional debugging" on my answer!

Comment: how to create a view user profile? anyone help do that, please?